# SQLite Database in android

Tags: android

Hii everybody ,

I am noob at android and need some help...

I am developing an app which requires me to write to an SQLiteDatabase in one activity and access it from another activity . I am facing a problem implementing this. Any suggestions/ideas as to how we can share the database across multiple activities ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class.

Simply use the same database name consistently across your activities, it should not cause any problem.

```
SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(
    context, R.string.db_name, null, 1);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to go about implementing the above statements? I am facing difficulties.

Comment: what about opening a new question ? it's been two years since my reply :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue of accessing the same database two different activities can be handled in a few different ways.

The simplest, which should work for your case, is to create a new class that extends SQLITEOpenHelper and instantiate that class from both activities.

Android has no problem with multiple Activities or processes accessing the SQlite database simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can make a common Class for DataBase and use it by creating object.

```
public class DbOperation extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String name="mydb.db";
public static final String MainTab="MainTab";
public static final String ID="_ID";
public static final String LevelName="LevelName";
int version =2;

public DbOperation(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name,null, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String str="CREATE TABLE "+MainTab+"("+ID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+LevelName+" text not null unique key)";     

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

Use this data base in any activity in below way

```
DbOperation ob=new DbOperation ();
SQLiteDatabase db=new SQLiteaDatabase();
db=ob.getWritableDataBase();

and now you can use operation like query,delete,update

 Cursor cur=db.query(Table_name,null,null,null,null); etc
```